# How did the Swooping Evil Venom infused rain affect the magical community?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

I didn't see any wizards drenched in the rain at the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (don't recall, actually). But would the rain equally affect the wizards as it did no-maj's?

This event is something that doesn't necessarily need to be forgotten by the Wizarding community. How would they avoid being obliviated by the rain?

(They could avoid the rain by Apparating, but what about the showers and drinking water?)

This question is picking at my brain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wizarding community seem very connected and not exactly few in number in the city of New York. I believe there would be support for wizards affected by large, magical events that occur, and the fact that any wizards dissenting from the cause may expose their world, MACUSA have an obvious and strong interest in containing any events, and the wizards involved. The raid on the underground speakeasy shows how magical people were controlled quickly and easily in the event of apprehending criminals- I imagine there’s a similarly strong focus on containing these events, preventing the non-magic community from finding out.

With regards to obliviation however, it would seem that those unaffected by the event may discuss and reveal the events to another wizard, and it would not be an issue. Frank’s activity was not a secret to the wizarding world, and so anyone who seemingly doesn’t remember can have the obliviation affect reversed.

Answer (score 2):

It should effect equally and also been proved by Queenie when she made umbrella by her wand before she entered rain to kiss Jacob Kowalski.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that.. ! but what about the water they drink and showers ? how would they avoid that ? And what about the wizards who absentmindedly come in contact with the rain / rainwater ?

Comment: I guess forewarned is forearmed; if they know the water will obliviate, they could counter it with a spell to counter it or maybe filter it. If they absent mindedly drink the water; I guess they'll be obliviated..

Comment: @Anu7 whole council know about it , so it can be prevented easily

Comment: I guess it's really not a definitive outcome.. !