# Why didn't obliviate spell work on wizards?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

I have just watched first part of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, and I can't understand the final scene. Rain influences everybody's memory except wizards. Is there is a spell which works against Obliviate spell? If there is no such spell, then why didn't it work on Jakob Kowalski?

Comment: I always wondered that - Credence's destruction was a bad memory to both Muggles and Wizards alike ! how did the selective obliviate even work ! what about unsuspecting wizards who were just happening to drink water and they forget all about the credence episode?

Comment: @Anu7 To be honest, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no spell. It was actually the venom of Swooping Evil which only erases the bad memories. Since Credence's attack created bad memories for everyone especially for no-maj, that venom wiped it out from everyone's mind affected by that rain.

There is no such thing that it'd only affect muggles. It can affect wizards as well as pointed out in [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63855/27264) and [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63856/27264). Queenie uses an umbrella to come out in the rain and the rest stay under the roof of that subway.

The reason why it didn't work on Jacob Kowalski, because the venom doesn't really obliviate everything except bad memories and he didn't have any as he said in *Fantastic Beasts: the Crimes of Grindelwald*.

Comment: So that means it also erased all bad memories of wizards?

Comment: Yes, of all wizards who got affected by that rain.